# Vee-validate 4, Yup nested object, an error has any type after setting initialValues

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, yup, vee-validate

I define vee-validate schema using composition api this way:

```js
import { useForm, useField } from 'vee-validate'
import { object, string } from 'yup'

const { handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
  validationSchema: object({
    currency: object().shape({
      name: string().notOneOf(['any'], errorMessages.required),
    }),
  }),
  // initialValues: {}
})
const { value: currency } = useField<SelectOption>('currency')
```

where

```js
export type SelectOption = {
  name: string
  label?: string
}
```

Then I pass my data and error to a child component:

```js
        <base-select
          v-model="currency"
          :options="currencies"
          :error="errors['currency.name']"
        />
```

And yes, `errors` contains `currency.name` at runtime and can't be accessed through `errors.currency.name`.

It builds just fine but after adding initial values like this

```js
  initialValues: {
    currency: {
      name: 'any',
      label: 'Choose currency',
    },
  }
```

It produces an error

```js
 Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"currency.name"' can't be used to index
type 'Partial<Record<"currency", string | undefined>>'.
  Property 'currency.name' does not exist on type 'Partial<Record<"currency", string | undefined>>'.

50           :error="errors['currency.name']"
```

That is, `currency` has `string` type but should have `SelectOption`. Or `errors` should have `currency.name` in types. Or am I doing something wrong?

Also, I tried to define `currency` field as

```js
const { value: currency } = reactive(useField<SelectOption>('currency'))
```

Made no difference

Packages used:

```json
"vee-validate": "^4.6.6",
"yup": "^0.32.11"
```